# FCTRL code chef too slow

Tags: c++

I am having some issues with my cpp code in code chef for the factorial problem.
http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL
I keep getting an error telling me it is too slow, and I was wondering if there was some way to speed it up?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Divisible_by_5(long &number)
{
  long hold = 0;
  int result = 0;
  if(number % 5 == 0)
    {
      result++;
      hold = number/5;
      while(hold % 5 == 0)
        {
          result++;
          hold = hold/5;
        }
    }
return result;
}

int Factorial_expansion(long &number)
{
  int result = 0;
  while(number > 4)
    {
      result += Divisible_by_5(number);
      number--;
    }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

  int *p_results_array;

  int lines;
  cin >> lines;

  p_results_array = new int [lines];

  for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
      long input;
      cin >> input;

      p_results_array[i] = Factorial_expansion(input);
    }
  for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
   {
      cout << p_results_array[i] << endl;
    }

 return 0;

}
```

EDIT
I ended up revising everything, and it turns out my math could've been way better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int lines;
  cin >> lines;

  while (lines--)
    {
      long input;
      cin >> input;

      int result = 0;

      for (int i = 1; pow(5, i) <= input; i++)
        result += input/pow(5, i);

      cout << result << endl;
   }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: where do you get this error?

Comment: I get the error after I submit my code to codechef. The site times how long execution takes, and this specific problem has an 8 second time limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do several things to speed it up. HTH.

One, separate inputs from processing, in the `main`. Then you can time your algo, not your typing speed. Something like

```
   for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
      long input;
      cin >> input;
      p_results_array[i] = input;
    }
   for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
      p_results_array[i] = Factorial_expansion( (long) p_results_array[i]);
    }
```

Two, keep a map of what you already got so that you don't have to re-do calcs, such as

```
#include <map>
map<long, long> fivepowers;
// and later, to check or set with known answers
```

Your `Divisible_by_5` can now be enhanced, somethng like - and notice I changed the input type of `const long&` so that you retain a functional interface

```
int Divisible_by_5(const long &number)
{
  long hold = number;
  int result = 0;
      while(hold % 5 == 0 )
        {
          result++;
          hold = hold/5;
          if ( fivepowers.find(hold) != fivepowers.end() ) return fivepowers[hold] + result;
        }
  fivepowers[number] = result;
  return result;
}
```

Lastly, you can improvise the `Factorial_expansion` knowing that the answer for 10,11,12,13,14 is the same as for 10. For the first pass, you need to find out how much ahead of a 5X you are, and bring the next number to an exact 5X. Thereafter, reduce by 5, not by 1. So, some math and some programming.

```
int Factorial_expansion(const long &number)
{
  long hold = number;
  int result = 0;
  int adjuster = number % 5;
  if ( adjuster == 0 ) adjuster = 5; // else you double-count sometimes
  while(hold > 4)
    {
      result += Divisible_by_5(hold);
      hold -= adjuster;
      adjuster = 5;
    }
  return result;
}
```

I will be curious what timing you get.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I took notes on the changes you recommended. The fivepowers map actually slowed down execution on my local machine, and I decided to remove it. I still can't get it under codechefs time limit, but I think I will start from scratch and try some other approach.

Comment: @Maurice how much was the performance slowed by the `map` as is? You can try to rewr it using `map<long,long>::iterator it = fivepowers.find(hold);` and use that `it` for test *and* access, thus avoiding a dupl search; does it improve perf?